# QDateTime::secsTo returns the same value for different QDateTime's

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdatetime

I recently wrote a stopwatch and noticed some strange behavior of `QDateTime::secsTo`. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature (or perhaps I only did a crappy implementation ;-).

My stopwatch code can be stripped down to this minimal example to produce the questionable result (at least on Linux using Qt 5.7.1):

**StopWatch.h**

```
#ifndef STOPWATCH_H
#define STOPWATCH_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QDateTime>

class QTimer;

class StopWatch : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit StopWatch(QWidget *parent);

private slots:
    void update();

private:
    QTimer *m_timer;
    QDateTime m_targetTime;
};

#endif // STOPWATCH_H
```

**StopWatch.cpp**

```
#include "StopWatch.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>

StopWatch::StopWatch(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    m_timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &StopWatch::update);
    m_targetTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime().addSecs(10);
    m_timer->start(1000);
}

void StopWatch::update()
{
    QDateTime currentDateTime = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    qint64 secondsLeft = currentDateTime.secsTo(m_targetTime);
    qDebug() << secondsLeft;
}
```

And here's (a part of) the output:

```
4
3
2
1
0
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
```

So here we are: `QDateTime::secsTo` outputs `0` for the same `QDateTime` *and* for a `QDateTime` one second before.

I worked around this by doing

```
if (currentDateTime <= m_targetTime) {
    secondsLeft++;
}
```

but I don't understand the behavoir. Why is this the case?

Comment: rounding issue? Perhaps you don't start exactly on a second.

Comment: It's always the same. Try the code – I ran this quite often before adding the workaround …

Comment: If I had a best guess, it would be that QDateTime::secsTo() is doing something weird with postive/negative integers. It looks like it is doing an integer ceiling for negative numbers, and an integer floor for positive numbers. Try switching to mSecsTo and report back.

Comment: I would be interested in the millisecond differences printed along with the second differences using QDateTime::msecsTo()

Comment: Looks better: e. g. 2998, 1999, 998, -2, -1002, -2002

Comment: Both 0.5 and -0.5 produce 0 when assigned to an integer.

Comment: Looks like the 2ms offset along with the integer truncation caused the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qdatetime.cpp

```
int QTime::secsTo(const QTime &t) const
{
    if (!isValid() || !t.isValid())
        return 0;

    // Truncate milliseconds as we do not want to consider them.
    int ourSeconds = ds() / 1000;
    int theirSeconds = t.ds() / 1000;
    return theirSeconds - ourSeconds;
}
```

It looks like it takes two positive integers that are under 1000, divides them by 1000, and then subtracts them from each other. If you use mSecsTo(), you will not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's a rounding issue. The `secsTo` function doesn't round to the nearest integer, but just drops the decimal part (this is what compilers do by default):

```
int QTime::secsTo(const QTime &t) const
{
    if (!isValid() || !t.isValid())
        return 0;

    // Truncate milliseconds as we do not want to consider them.
    int ourSeconds = ds() / 1000;
    int theirSeconds = t.ds() / 1000;
    return theirSeconds - ourSeconds;
}
```

or 4.x version:

```
int QTime::secsTo(const QTime &t) const
{
    return (t.ds() - ds()) / 1000;
}
```

So what you probably see is:

```
 4.8 -> 4
 3.8 -> 3
 2.8 -> 2
 1.8 -> 1
 0.8 -> 0
-0.2 -> 0
-1.2 -> -1
-2.2 -> -2
-3.2 -> -3
-4.2 -> -4
```

For the expected result, use something like:

```
qint64 secondsLeft = qRound64(currentDateTime.msecsTo(m_targetTime) / 1000.0);
```